# Windows error 126 when opening proficy Hmi/Scada

Tags: plc, scada

Hi I was trying to run a program (Proficy Hmi) but I got more than one dll error, Windows error 126

I have attached all the error images here with the Windows version

Device type ("All-in-One" 15-panel marine)
Windows version (Windows XP for embedded systems)

Also I downloaded all the missing dll files but it didn't solve the problem

**I can't change Windows**

[Picture of: ifix startup . version 4.0 [build 6192]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCoE8.jpg)

[Picture of: ifix startup program error code : 126](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zh7X3.jpg)

[Picture of : ifix startup error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xClza.jpg)

[Picture of:startup history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtXRK.jpg)

Comment: The image _ifix startup error_ clearly shows that you are missing the _Tþi.dll_. Beeing unable to load that specific DLL seems like a valid reason to me for receiving the described error code. Have you tried copying this file into the _C:\windows\system32_ directory and restarted the system before trying to start the software?